# Passport authorization_code grant

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-passport

I think I'm missing something trying to get `authorization_code` grant working. I have passport setup successfully with both password grant and client credentials grant working. Another team wants to integrate with our API, and we need to track which users do which things (the client credentials grant is tied to a single user account).

When I try to make a GET request to `/oauth/authorize`, my API is returning a 401 error, which I think is wrong, but when I look in the passport source I find in passport's [`RouteRegistrar`](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/4.0/src/RouteRegistrar.php#L48):

```
$this->router->group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function ($router) {
    $router->get('/authorize', [
        'uses' => 'AuthorizationController@authorize',
    ]);
```

Why would the authorize route need to check if a user is logged in via the `auth` middleware? I would expect a user to expressly *not* be logged in to hit this route. Do I need to intercept the request myself, ask for credentials and log the user in, then redirect back to this route to get the authorization code?

**Update**

Using @Jeffrey's comment below as a starting point, I've gotten it to work *after* I realized the `redirect_uri` query parameter also must match the `redirect` attribute of the `oauth_cient`.

Comment: It actually makes sense. Before you can authorize a different application, the user should be logged in to your site (`AuthorizationController` phpDoc says: "Authorize a client to access the user's account.") to prove they're able to authorize an application.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate that a bit? I'm stuck at the same point as you before. When I use for example oauth from facebook or google, they ask me as well my credentials in a popup/redirect. Why not smth similar in laravel?

Why should a client first login (by password grant or what?) and then request a authorization code again? At this point he already must have had an access token, no?

Comment: @Chris The login in this grant is happening on the 3rd party service. The popup from facebook is actually an iframe loading content from facebook. Once you login _to Facebook_, Facebook then needs to ask the user to approve the request of your app. After approved, facebook will then redirect the user to the `redirect` attribute of your client with the _authorization code_ which your app can then exchange for a valid _token_. The code -> token exchange is necessary because of how HTTP works, the originating service doesn't know after the redirect what happens until the exchange is requested.

Comment: @Chris I am assuming (falsely) that Facebook is using Laravel to handle this exchange, just as an example of my understanding as to how Laravel handles this.

Comment: Hm confusing, I'm not sure if I got it. 1. The user needs an access token to consume the  laravel api. 2. To get an access token he makes a redirect to laravel, requesting an authorization code. 3. This Code he can exchange for the access token. Alright, but when he needs to login first (=getting an access token, by grant_type password or how else is he supposed to?) to even request the authorization code, then he logs in twice, which obviously does not make sense. Where am I wrong here?

Comment: I think I see where you're having trouble. The login action could be performed via password grant on the API's side or through normal Laravel authentication. It has nothing to do with granting the API access to _your app_. It is external to your app, it is logging in to the first party App, whereas with with authorization code grant it is generally assumed the integration is with a 3rd party app. If the user is already authenticated in the first party app then no authentication needs to be performed, it just asks the user to approve the 3rd party (i.e. your app)  request.

Comment: I think I figured it out. You are right. The thing that caused the confusion was that I had messed around with the automated login redirect of laravel. Therefore I always got a json response 401 instead of the login window. Now it makes more sense.
Thanks for the responses.